# Can you move on your turn, and then use the Ready Action to move again on another creature's turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, actions, readied-action

The [Ready](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Ready) action is described as follows:

> First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose the action you will take in response to that trigger, or you choose to move up to your speed in response to it.

So, is there anything preventing you from moving your full speed and then taking the Ready action for another (off-turn) full-speed movement? The above quote seems to allow it, but it just feels slightly weird to me, so maybe there's something else prohibiting it.

Increasing your speed is of course no reasonable motivation for such a strategy, since you might as well just take the Dash action. This strategy however would effectively let you split up your Dash speed over your and someone else's turn, which might come in handy here and there - even though it costs your reaction.

Comment: Related: [What are the basic limitations for using a Reaction to move? Does movement used on your Turn matter?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124103/what-are-the-basic-limitations-for-using-a-reaction-to-move-does-movement-used)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### This plan works

You have already quoted the relevant ready rules which state that you can use the Ready action to move.

The [rules for what you can do on your turn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#YourTurn) are simply:

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed and take one action.

So, you can choose to move up to your speed. Then, for your action, simply take the Ready action, choosing to move in response to some perceivable circumstance.

It is difficult to prove a negative, but there really is nothing else in the rules that prohibits this plan under normal circumstances. The Ready action is simply one of the many action options you can take during your turn. The action you choose to take does not influence whether you can move, and neither does moving affect what actions you can take (any exceptions to this would have to be noted in the rules for those specific actions, but nothing in the Ready action description suggests such a limitation).

Note that the disadvantage of this over Dashing is that this does require you to spend your reaction.

Answer (score -2):

### No, Movement is limited per round.

This does not work as you are limited to [only moving your speed in a single **round**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Speed):

> Every character and monster has a speed, which is the distance in feet that the character or monster can walk in 1 round.

The [dash action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Dash) is an exception to this as it grants **extra** movement:

> When you take the Dash action, you gain extra movement for the current turn. The increase equals your speed, after applying any modifiers.

(n.b., for the rules to be watertight, the quoted passage for dash would have to say 'current round' not 'current turn', but the two words are used inconsistently, and reading the 'extra turns' movement *not* counting as 'extra round' movement as well would prevent dash ever granting extra movement.)

The readied action does not grant extra movement for the current round, turn or otherwise.

Even if your readied action is triggered next round, you would be limited to your speed's worth of movement on that round's turn, unless you used the dash action on that turn. That is if your readied movement is the round after you readied it, on your turn you would be considered to have used up your whole movement, barring any extra granted.

You could however, use part of your movement on your turn, and the rest as part of your readied movement in the same round.

Comment: I am downvoting this because this interpretation of movement means spells such as *wall of stone* are incredibly strong (the reaction to escape can rarely be used) and spells such as *dissonant whispers* are almost useless (the reaction hardly ever moves them). I feel that if reaction-based movement were limited by what you had already done on your turn, this would be much more explicit than it is

Comment: @Exempt-Medic you'd hope so wouldn't you? I might edit this to explain I think this is dumb, and how I'd rule it but I don't have any experience running 5e games to say either way.